# in jQuery, set spans with same class to display:inline from :block

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, is there a way to select all tag that reference a specific css class, and set the display to "inline"?

example:

```
<span class="theclass">junk</span>
<span class="theclass">other junk</span>
<span class="theclass">more junk</span>
```

in .css:

```
.theclass {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(".theclass").css("display", "inline");
```

or maybe

```
$(".theclass").show();
```